# Posterior mode estimator unchanged under coordinate transformation?

Tags: bayesian, posterior, estimators

I'm looking at a data set where the posterior mode has noticeably less "bias" than the posterior mean and posterior median, and somewhat less error.  However, the posterior mode is not invariant under coordinate transformation.  So, I was considering reporting the mode of the posterior/prior.  This should be invariant under coordinate transformations.

Is there an approach that fits better with Bayesian philosophical leanings?  Unlike the median and the mean, this doesn't seem to be based on minimizing a posterior risk.  But it does look kind of like a Bayes factor.

Also, is there a name for this kind of thing?

-BenRI

Comment: Much about this question is unclear. Because the mean is not invariant under data transformations, it is not apparent what distinction you are trying to make in the first paragraph.  Also, since you refer both to a "posterior" and a "prior," presumably you are already adopting a "Bayesian approach."  How, then, could it possibly become "more Bayesian"?  Note, too, that no *data set* of itself has a "posterior mode": the very calculation of any posterior distribution from data (apart from the empirical one) supposes a model for the data. What is your model? Finally, what is a "posterior/prior"?

Comment: (1) I edited the question to mention the median as well, which is invariant under coordinate transformations. (2) I think there is more to a Bayesian approach than simply computing a posterior distribution. For example, reporting a point estimate that minimizes a posterior expected loss may fit better with Bayesian philosophy than some other methods.  Then there is the "likelihood principle", etc. (4) By posterior/prior, I mean the ratio of the posterior density to the prior density.

Comment: (3)  I'm interested in estimating a parameter s from genetic data.  The model places a uniform prior on s (the "selfing rate") that runs from 0 to 1.  There is a also a likelihood on s based on the observed genotypes. The uniform prior is more of a default choice than a well-thought-out decision.

Answer (score 3):

There is a name for reporting the mode of the posterior divided by the prior.  It is called the maximum-likelihood estimate.

If you want a Bayesian point estimate that is invariant under coordinate transformations then look into [intrinsic estimation](http://www.uv.es/~bernardo/BernardoJuarez.pdf).

Comment: The maximum likelihood estimate is invariant under coordinate transformations so the poster is probably doing a MAP estimate, which isn't.

Comment: In some cases, it is indeed the ML estimate.  Good point.  However, if there is more than one parameter (which there is in my case) it seems to be called the Maximum Marginal Likelihood (MML) estimate.